# How to add an optional parameters/default value parameters in VB function?

Tags: vb.net, parameters, optional-parameters

How can I create a method that has optional parameters in it in Visual Basic?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use the `Optional` keyword and supply a default value. Optional parameters must be the last parameters defined, to avoid creating ambiguous function signatures.

```vb
Sub MyMethod(ByVal Param1 As String, Optional ByVal FlagArgument As Boolean = True)
    If FlagArgument Then
        'Do something special
        Console.WriteLine(Param1)
    End If

End Sub
```

Call it like this:

```vb
MyMethod("test1")
```

Or like this:

```vb
MyMethod("test2", False)
```

Comment: Didn't realize this was gonna be a 'canned' question.  Oh well.

Comment: It wasn't covered here, so I thought I would add what I found from the Google result.

Answer (score 2):

Have in mind that optional argument cannot have place before a required argument.

This code will show error:

```
Sub ErrMethod(Optional ByVal FlagArgument As Boolean = True, ByVal Param1 As String)
    If FlagArgument Then
        'Do something special
        Console.WriteLine(Param1)
    End If
End Sub
```

It is common error, no much explained by debugger...
It have sense, imagine the call...

```
ErrMethod(???, Param1)
```